# D3.js Drag svg element over other element and detect it

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, drag-and-drop

Hy,

So lets say I have two rect elements:
A: not draggable 
B: draggable

And what I want is when I drag B (with the help of d3.js) and after dragging release it on A, I want to detect this.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the location of A and the location of B and see if they overlap. getBoundingClientRect will help with the location part.

Comment: @RobertLongson The problem is that actually i have more A elements like  a lot more.. i can have hundreds and they can be spread out on my canvas so its a bit tricky

Comment: Sounds like a job for [collision detection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298)

Comment: @Mr.Sam hello, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Margo i did it in a different way, i wanted to connect to elements with dragging one on the other but in the end i went with dragging a line from A to B and then connect it.

Comment: Hey, may be you can set some flags for mouseover on A, when you dragend B. you can compare the flags to make sure that you landed up on A.